# How to monitor / log files access to remote folders under windows?

Tags: c++, windows, networking, file, monitoring

I would like to log the name of all the files I access from a particular network share (and the process accessing the the file).

What are the solutions in C++ / Win32 preferably ?

Answer (score 2):

You need [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx) and the FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS notification flag.

I don't think the old FindFirstChangeNotification will work for you as it only notifies on changes, not access, but I've traditionally used that for file/directory notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Process Monitor from sysinternals.com can be set up to filter on the path. You can set the path to the UNC you're interested in watching.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it's for after-the-fact, you could use the [Windows' security auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772690%28WS.10%29.aspx).

If you need to do it in real-time, then you might need to interface with the [Windows message queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and sniff the specific events that interest you.